# error while playing mp3 from assets folder phonegap(Cordova)

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I just started learning `phonegap` but I'm getting the error `alert('no audio support!');` when I click on the play button to play and mp3 from the `assets` folder. I have searched a lot of code to play mp3  and what I have so far is shown here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
<!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
<meta name="viewport"
    content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<title>Hello World</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Toast.js"></script>
<script>
    function playStream() {
        try {
            var myaudio = new Media('/android_asset/www/audio/limelight.mp3');
            //alert ("ffff");

            myaudio.id = 'playerMyAdio';
            myaudio.play();
        } catch (e) {
            alert('no audio support!');
        }
    }

    function getMediaURL(s) {
        if (device.platform.toLowerCase() === "android")
            return "/android/assets/www/" + s;
        return s;
    }

    function stopStream() {
        try {
            myaudio.pause();
        } catch (e) {
            alert('no audio support!');
        }
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
            <h1>Play AUdio</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <button onClick="playStream()">play</button>
            <br />
            <button onClick="stopStream()">stop</button>
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have improved your wording and added the detail you missed earlier. That should help you get an answer.

Comment: Sorry from my side, I was wrong. If you once took name of floating view service, I could got that quickly.

Comment: no worries , appreciate that :) , you can email me as well

Answer (score 0):

@quick learner, which OS are you doing this for? Which OS are you having problems with? Your code shows Windows, iOS, and Android. This code might work for Android. I have [working examples for iOS and Android](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap-Media-Test). --Jesse

Comment: @quicklearner, Okay. Start by cleaning up your code. Those extra points for Windows and iOS are not well documented, so they are likely adding noise in your head. Download my demos here: http://codesnippets.altervista.org/examples/phonegap/demos/PUBLIC.Apps.html  You want *Phonegap-Media-Test* FWIW, mp3 is documented to work with Android, but I think you need the correct SDK level. If you use OGG, like I have, then it does not matter.

Comment: well i read it and appreciate your concern ... i used a code but still not able to play it ...

Comment: I recently found out that Phonegap CLI has a different path system from Phonegap Build. Strip out everything, just get the audio to play, then add it back. You DO NOT NEED jquery, jquerymobile or toast to have audio play. Your problem is simple, but your choice of tools creates noise, not a solution. My first audio app had NO GUI, it just played the sound.

Comment: I posted the information on google groups earlier. Here is the URL  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/J6kWRdmtmIg

Comment: I have given you my code for working apps that play audio -- three times already.